# FatFreeFramework sent JSON by using Web component and method POST

Tags: php, json, post, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to send a post from my app written in f3. I followed this documentation https://fatfreeframework.com/3.5/web#POST, but I don't know how to send JSON. In curl it is params -d. My call by curl is:

```
curl -d '{"text":"Hello.","port":[2,3],"param":[{"number":"1","text_param":["Yes"]}]}’ –H "Content-Type:application/json" http://ip.com/api/send -u usr:pass
```

How do I do it in f3?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use F3 or just use cURL itself in php. Since you asked for F3 I'll put an example below. You can also learn more from this link [here in the documentation](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.7/web#request)

F3

```php
<?php

$options = [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'content' => '{"text":"Hello.","port":[2,3],"param":[{"number":"1","text_param":["Yes"]}]}',
    'header' => [ 
        'Content-Type: application/json' 
        'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode('usr:pass')
    ]
];
$result = \Web::instance()->request('http://ip.com/api/send', $options);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, after comparing your solution with mine I found out, that I had missplaced the method option and placed it into the header array.